Blender doesn't bake inverse kinemtaics on .glb export for Godot
so i'm still working on the same game, and I set up the directional walking animations. I pushed them down into NLA tracks to import into Godot. For some reason, on my first export, Blender automatically created keyframes for bones that were on empty tracks in the animation. Turning sampling off in the export menu fixed this, however, now none of the inverse kinematics in the animations are exporting, which stops the leg animations from working when they get imported into Godot. How can I stop blender from automatically creating keyframes for empty tracks, while still having inverse kinematics for animations that use them?

Nevermind, I figured out the issue. I had to re-enable sampling, otherwise the IK wouldn't work, and then I turned on "reset bones between actions", along with "Optimize animations". This fixed it.
